# How to install "Code With Me" plugin with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jetbrains-ide

Code With Me plugin from JetBrains now works with Android Studio. However each version of the plugin is compatible with a specific build of Android Studio according to this [page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14896-code-with-me/versions).

However, Android Studio [download page](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) lists only releases. How can I easily find out build number of each Android Studio version, so I could download a version that's compatible with Code With Me plugin?

Comment: *"How can I easily find out build number of each Android Studio version"* `Help | About` in Android Studio and see the build number there: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/user_images/GQ57OPz4b-613s6jp_FDAg.png P.S. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CWM-1983 -- see the last comment in particular.

Comment: Thank you @LazyOne will try doing that, comment should help me get the plugin working with that particular canary 5 version of Android Studio. I still don't know how to find version of plugin compatible with some older stable version of Android Studio.

Comment: I was able to install the plugin based on the last comment, thanks.

Comment: Make it as an answer then -- will help other users in a similar situation (Question with accepted Answer is much more visible than a bunch of comments (even if they contain the solution)). Describe what exactly you did (clicked/entered; with screenshots is possible) and what versions were used in your case. The more info the better (easier to compare to own environment/see how relevant it is).

Answer (score 0):

> Help | About

in Android Studio and see the build number there: intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/user_images/…

P.S. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CWM-1983